# Abreviating a ship name with an apostrophe?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, apostrophe, proper-nouns

If a ship is named the *Scienta Victoria*, and I wish to drop the first word for the sake of brevity, is it proper to place an apostrophe before the "*Victoria*" to signify the dropped word?

Comment: 'Obama met up with 'Putin. In Washington'. In other news, Brad' married Jennifer'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No apostrophe needed. From [today’s news](http://www.washingtonpost.com/local/navy-christens-the-future-aircraft-carrier-uss-gerald-r-ford-at-ceremony-in-virginia/2013/11/09/079d1912-4966-11e3-b87a-e66bd9ff3537_story.html):

> NORFOLK, Va. — The Navy christened the USS Gerald Ford on Saturday with the traditional smashing of a bottle of sparkling wine across the bow of the ship — the most technologically advanced aircraft carrier the United States has built.
>
> The Ford is the lead ship in the Navy’s next class of nuclear-powered aircraft carriers.

And later in the same piece:

> The Ford — with a new nuclear power plant, electromagnetic catapults and an enhanced 5-acre flight deck — will leave dry dock and head to a pier at Newport News Shipbuilding next week.

From NOAD:

> **apostrophe** (*noun*)
> a punctuation mark ( ’ ) used to indicate either possession e.g., *Harry’s book; boys’s coats*) or the omission of ***letters*** or ***numbers*** [emphasis added] (e.g., *can’t; he’s; class of ’99*)

So, feel at liberty to tell everyone about the expeditions of the *Victoria*, provided that you clarify by mentioning the full name of the ship sometime earlier in the text.

Comment: I'm glad you put in that proviso.